# Solid bars in bar chart with react-native-chart-kit

Tags: react-native, react-native-chart-kit

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit and am trying to make a chart to match the following design spec:

[image]

I can get most of the options to work with the code attached at the end of this question, however I can't seem to figure out how to remove the opacity of each individual bar, so it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I've been poring through the source code and playing with props and styles to no avail.. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get('window');

export type DataSet = {
  data: Array<Number>;
};

export type BarChartData = {
  labels: Array<String>;
  datasets: Array<DataSet>;
};

export interface SalesChartProps {
  data: BarChartData;
}

const chartConfig = {
  backgroundGradientFrom: '#Ffffff',
  backgroundGradientTo: '#ffffff',
  barPercentage: 1.3,
  decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(1, 122, 205, 1)`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`,

  style: {
    borderRadius: 16,
    fontFamily: 'Bogle-Regular',
  },
  propsForBackgroundLines: {
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: '#efefef',
    strokeDasharray: '0',
  },
  propsForLabels: {
    fontFamily: 'Bogle-Regular',
  },
};

const SalesBarChart: FunctionComponent<SalesChartProps> = (
  props: SalesChartProps,
) => (
  <>
    <Text style={styles.chartTitle}> Sales </Text>
    <BarChart
      style={styles.graphStyle}
      showBarTops={false}
      showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
      withInnerLines={true}
      segments={3}
      data={props.data}
      width={screenWidth - 15}
      height={175}
      yAxisLabel=""
      chartConfig={chartConfig}
      verticalLabelRotation={0}
    />
  </>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create<{
  graphStyle: ViewStyle;
  chartTitle: TextStyle;
}>({
  graphStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingRight: 25,
  },
  chartTitle: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Bogle-Regular',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
})

//storybook file:
const data: BarChartData = {
  labels: ['9/19', '9/20', '9/21', '9/22', '9/23', '9/24', '9/25'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [5, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 0],
    },
  ],
};

const props = {
  data,
};

storiesOf('SalesChart', module)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .add('BarChart', () => <SalesChart {...props} />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do this as of now for the `BarChart` component as the fill of the `Rect` components that represent the bars are all set to a gradient `fillShadowGradient` (https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/blob/master/src/BarChart.tsx).

You can however change the color for these bars and their opacity by changing the following properties in the `chartConfig`:

```
fillShadowGradient: 'blue',
fillShadowGradientOpacity: 1,
```

If the opacity is set to `1` the color does look *more* solid, but the gradient remains.

---

An alternative approach is to use a `StackedBarChart` and put each element in your `data` in their own array so the bars don't stack:

```
const CustomStackedChart = () => {
  const data = {
    labels: ['9/19', '9/20', '9/21', '9/22', '9/23', '9/24', '9/25'],
    legend: [],
    data: [[5], [0], [2], [4], [6], [3], [0]],
    barColors: ['blue'],
  };
  return (
    <StackedBarChart
      style={styles.graphStyle}
      segments={3}
      data={data}
      width={300}
      height={175}
      chartConfig={chartConfig}
    />
  );
};
```

The `StackedBarChart` does allow a solid color. The color can be set by setting the `barColors` prop inside the data object.

The problem with this approach is that you can't have the bar labels on top of the bars like you have in your picture:

[image: stacked bar chart showcase]

---

If you really want to create something custom you could create a custom chart component that extends `AbstractChart`, but this is quite a lot of work to create if the only thing you really want to change is the color of the bars to solid.

https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit#abstract-chart.

Comment: https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/blob/master/src/BarChart.tsx#L82 is this the line you are referring to? i am trying to fork this and adding a `barFill` property to override the `fill="url(#fillShadowGradient)"`  but am a bit unsure how this is working to pass in the gradient as this doesnt look like traditional string interpolation

Comment: Yes that's the line. `url` is a css function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url() that can be used to point to a resource (the gradient with id fillShadowGradient in this case). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url.

Comment: ok thank you... my logic is to replace that url function with a simple `rgba()` or hex string value, hopefully this works

Answer (score 6):

I found this horrible solution, if you use height in the chart config and place it a very high number the bar seems solid, example:

```
const chartConfig = {
  backgroundGradientFrom: "#fff",
  backgroundGradientTo: "#fff",
  barPercentage: 0.7,
  height:5000,
  fillShadowGradient: `rgba(1, 122, 205, 1)`,
  fillShadowGradientOpacity: 1,
  decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
  color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(1, 122, 205, 1)`,
  labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)`,

  style: {
    borderRadius: 16,
    fontFamily: "Bogle-Regular",
  },
  propsForBackgroundLines: {
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: "#e3e3e3",
    strokeDasharray: "0",
  },
  propsForLabels: {
    fontFamily: "Bogle-Regular",
  },
};
```

[image]

Comment: lmao thats a funny yet effective way, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can pass individual colors and active flatColor

```
withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
flatColor={true}
```

**Sample**

```
const data = { 
            labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7","8","9"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    data: [40, 84, 56, 40, 60, 55, 40, 72, 40],
                    colors: [
                        (opacity = 1) => `#BE95FF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#78A9FF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                        (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
                    ]
                } 
            ]
        }; 



<BarChart 
  style={{
  marginLeft: - Metrics.padding * 4
  }}
  data={data}
  width={chartStyles.chart.width}
  height={chartStyles.chart.height} 
  chartConfig={{ 
  backgroundColor: "transparent",
  backgroundGradientTo: "white",
  backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
  backgroundGradientFrom: "white",
  backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
  color: (opacity = 1) => `#FFFFFF`,
  barPercentage: 0.28,
  barRadius : 5,  
 }}
 withHorizontalLabels={false}
 fromZero={true}
 withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
 flatColor={true}
 withInnerLines={false}
 showBarTops={false}
 showValuesOnTopOfBars={true}
 />
```

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O42Pn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set the fillShadowGradientFrom and fillShadowGradientTo to the same color and set both fillShadowGradientFromOpacity and fillShadowGradientToOpacity to 1:

```
fillShadowGradientFrom: `#017acd`,
fillShadowGradientFromOpacity: 1,
fillShadowGradientTo: `#017acd`,
fillShadowGradientToOpacity: 1,
```

This will result in the bars having solid color.

```
const chartConfig = {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    backGroundGradientTo: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundGradientToOpacity: 0,
    backGroundGradientFrom: "#FFFFFF",
    backgroundGradientFromOpacity: 0,
    /* THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT */
    fillShadowGradientFrom: `#017acd`,
    fillShadowGradientFromOpacity: 1,
    fillShadowGradientTo: `#017acd`,
    fillShadowGradientToOpacity: 1,
    /* ************* */
    barPercentage: 1,
    decimalPlaces: 0,
    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(9, 136, 205, ${opacity})`,
    labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
    style: {
        borderRadius: 0
    }
};
const chartWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
```

Barchart:

```
<BarChart
   data={{
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
          datasets: [
             {
                 data: [
                         Math.random() * 10,
                         Math.random() * 10,
                         Math.random() * 10
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }}
    width={chartWidth}
    height={250}
    yAxisLabel="R"
    yAxisSuffix="m"
    withInnerLines={false}
    chartConfig={chartConfig}
    verticalLabelRotation={30}
    withHorizontalLabels={true}
    fromZero={false}
    withCustomBarColorFromData={false}
    showBarTops={false}
    showValuesOnTopOfBars={false}
 />
```

[Bar chart with solid color bars (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXOLV.png)