# React Native Chart Kit - BarChart color fading out of each bar from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, frontend

I am using react native chart kit `yarn add react-native-chart-kit` to visualize data and this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import RandomColor from "randomcolor";
import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart,
} from "react-native-chart-kit";

const Chart = ({ classList }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Bezier Line Chart</Text>
      <BarChart
        data={{
          labels: classList.map((classItem) => {
            return classItem.classname;
          }),
          datasets: [
            {
              data: classList.map((classItem) => {
                return classItem.studentList.length;
              }),
            },
          ],
        }}
        width={Dimensions.get("window").width} 
        height={220}
        yAxisInterval={1} 
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
          backgroundGradientFrom: "#ffffff",
          backgroundGradientTo: "#ffffff",
          decimalPlaces: 2, 
          color: () => "blue",
          labelColor: () => "black",
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16,
          },
          propsForDots: {
            r: "6",
            strokeWidth: "1",
            stroke: "#ffa726",
          },
        }}
        bezier
        style={{
          marginVertical: 8,
          borderRadius: 16,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

and this is how it returned:

[image: screen shot]

As you can see, it worked, but not perfectly.  The color at the end of each bar gradually fades out from top to bottom and it is not good with the white backgroundColor. So, I want to make the color of each bar solid.  Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solid bars in bar chart with react-native-chart-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035350/solid-bars-in-bar-chart-with-react-native-chart-kit)

Comment: thank you so much but i switch to learn Flutter instead of RN, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

use `flatColor={true}` & `withCustomBarColorFromData={true}`

like this

```
 const data = {
        labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
        datasets: [{
                data: [50, 45, 28],
                colors: [
                    () => "blue"
                ]}]
 };
<BarChart
                
     data={data}
     width={Dimensions.get("window").width - 20}
     height={220}
     chartConfig={{
       //....
     }}
     withCustomBarColorFromData={true}
     flatColor={true}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

After using above answer `flatColor={true}` & `withCustomBarColorFromData={true}`

if you want color as dynamic in dataset use below code:

```
 const data = {
        labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3"],
        datasets: [
                  {
                     data: [50, 45, 28],
                    colors: data.colorName.map(item => {
                      return () => item.color;
                    }),
                  },
                ],
 };
```

Comment: The answer is mostly copy-pasting the other answer. It does not answer the actual question, but adds additional information to it.

Comment: Hey @AxelMeier, I just want to say how to pass color dynamic, using above answer.